# How to update multiple rows each with different condition in a single query in Cakephp 3?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0, query-builder, upsert

I need to update multiple rows in a single query in CakePHP 3. To insert the multiple rows I have used the following queries:

```
$Users = $this->Users->newEntities($insertDataArray);

$this->Users->saveMany($users);
```

But now I have to update multiple rows each with a different condition. I have multiple arrays and using for loop, I am iterating each array and updating the table rows. This is a  bad practice and I want to update the data in a single query.

```
foreach($mainArray as $updateArray){
  $this->Users->updateAll([$updateArray],'account_id'=>$updateArray['account_id']]);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do that update in plain SQL? If so you will find a way to translate that query in cakephp (and someone will help you if you post your efforts so far), otherwise the loop is the only way

Comment: Depending on the format of your data, `patchEntities` followed by `saveMany` might work fine, but that's not "a single query". Not clear whether you really want to have only a single query, or just avoid the loop in your code; `saveMany` eliminates the loop in *your* code, but only by doing it somewhere else.

Comment: @GregSchmidt - I am inserting multiple rows with saveMany method which is a single query.Now,  I want  to update the multiple rows in a single query based on condition and avoid the loop which update one row at a time.